# Best practice for programmatically showing UIView in correct orientation

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview, xamarin.ios, uiinterfaceorientation

I am building an monoTouch-iPad application and I am stumbling around because of the start-interface-orientation.

One problem is, when the app starts `UIDevice.CurrentDevice.Orientation` always returns `Unknown`. How can you decide in which orientation your app starts? All properties that I found by now just return portrait-mode, unknown or the frame-size of portrait mode - even if it's landscape mode.

I also created two UIViews (one for landscape, one for portrait) and changing them by now in the `WillRotate` method of the UIViewController. But my code:

```
if(toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight){

        _scrollView.RemoveFromSuperview();
        this.View.Add (_scrollViewLandscape);
        }else{
        _scrollViewLandscape.RemoveFromSuperview();
        this.View.Add (_scrollView);
}
```

produces a short and ugly "flickering" when rotating the screen - at least in the simulator.

Is there a best practice for laying out your Views? And I know about `ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`but this doesn't work for me, as I am doing much owner drawn stuff, which gets broken when autoresized ([see my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428427/filling-background-on-ipad-doesnt-fill-whole-screen-in-landscape-mode)).

I would really appreciate a solution without using the Interface-Builder, as I am doing everything in code by now.

**UPDATE:** Short-Descripton what I want to achieve:
AppStart -> knowing the correct Framsize (1024,748 or 768,1004) -> Adding my custom view in correct framesize

**UPDATE2:** simple and basic code-snippet

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();            
        Console.WriteLine (this.InterfaceOrientation);
    }
```

returns portrait. Even if the simulator is in landscape-mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

inside your UIViewController can just check the InterfaceOrientation

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    if (this.InterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait
        || this.InterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        // portrait
    }
    else
    {
        // landsacpe
    }
}
```

but i would really recommend using View.AutoresizingMask or overriding LayoutSubviews, both makes the all the transitions really smooth

**UPDATE: using AutoresizingMask**

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    UIView view = new CustomView(View.Bounds);
    view.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight |  UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth;
    View.AddSubview(view);
}
```

**UPDATE: overriding LayoutSubviews**

LayoutSubviews is called everytime the Size changes

```
public class CustomView : UIView
{
    public override void LayoutSubviews ()
    {
        //layout your view with your own logic using the new values of Bounds.Width and Bounds.Height
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but at app-start `this.InterfaceOrientation` returns `Portrait` even if the simulator is in landscape mode.

Comment: How to correctly use the AutoresizingMask with ownerdrawn Views? And what would be the benefits of overriding LayoutSubviews?

Comment: I can't get to work what I want with the Autoresizing Masks, but how should I work in the LayoutSubviews? With Transformations or by replacing the whole view?

Comment: you can do what ever you want: hide views, set frame of view, apply transformation, start animations